# Change "0 items" on Safari iOS / default webkit behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, webkit

I have a select multiple element that I alter using JavaScript on desktop but would like to preserve the default iOS/webkit behavior when viewing a page on iOS [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5ZOr.png).

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

However, when on mobile the default title for the select bar is "0 items" and then if 2 things are selected it displays "2 items".

I understand Webkit is the engine for Safari and so it's what is rendering the dropdown. Is there any way to alter this "0 items" text to not say items and instead say something like "0 specialties" or something of the like?

Thanks!